# When using Twitter Bootstrap 3's Grid, panel-body overlaps the navbar-header

Tags: javascript, html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3, bootstrap-grid

For some reason when I'm using col-xs-* inside the panel-body, the content overlaps the panel-heading when I scroll down. This doesn't happen when I remove the col-xs-* and row tags.

Before Scrolling down:

[image: panel with Bootstrap grid layouts]

After Scrolling down:

[image: panel content hides the navbar-header]

Source Code:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html dir="ltr" lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, user-scalable=no">
 <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css" integrity="sha384-rHyoN1iRsVXV4nD0JutlnGaslCJuC7uwjduW9SVrLvRYooPp2bWYgmgJQIXwl/Sp" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-Tc5IQib027qvyjSMfHjOMaLkfuWVxZxUPnCJA7l2mCWNIpG9mGCD8wGNIcPD7Txa" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <style>
  .navbar-collapse {
    background-color: #69899f;
    border-color: #425766;
  }

  .navbar-header {
    background-color: #69899f;
    border-color: #425766;
  }
  .navbar-collapse .navbar-text {
    color: #d7e2e9;
  }
  .navbar-header .navbar-toggle .icon-bar {
    background-color: #d7e2e9;
  }
        .affix {
            top: 0;
            width: 100%;
        }

        .affix+.container-fluid {
            padding-top: 70px;
        }
    </style>
</head>

<body>
 <div class="navbar fixed-top clearfix" style="border:1px solid #000;">
  <div class="navbar-header">
   <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse">
    <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
   </button>
   <h2 style="margin-top: 8px;margin-bottom: 8px;margin-right: 80px">Title A</h2>
  </div>
  <nav class="collapse navbar-collapse">
   <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
    <li class="active"><a href="#menu1">Title B</a></li>
   </ul>
  </nav><!--/.nav-collapse -->
    </div>
 
 <div class="container-fluid">
  <div class="tab-content clearfix">
   <div id="menu1" class="tab-pane fade in active">
    <h1 class="text-center">Title B</h1><br>
    <div class="container" id="niftarim">

  <div class="widget">
   <div class="panel panel-info">
   <div class="panel-heading"><p>Header</p></div>
   <div class="panel-body" style="word-wrap: break-word;">
    <div class="row">
     <div class="col-xs-3">
      <img src="http://placehold.it/40x140">
     </div>
     <div class="col-xs-9">
      <p>bla bla bla</p>
     </div>
    </div>
   </div>
   </div>
  </div>
  
  <div class="widget">
   <div class="panel panel-info">
   <div class="panel-heading"><p>Header</p></div>
   <div class="panel-body" style="word-wrap: break-word;">
    <div class="row">
     <div class="col-xs-3">
      <img src="http://placehold.it/40x140">
     </div>
     <div class="col-xs-9">
      <p>bla bla bla</p>
     </div>
    </div>
   </div>
   </div>
  </div>
  
  <div class="widget">
   <div class="panel panel-info">
   <div class="panel-heading"><p>Header</p></div>
   <div class="panel-body" style="word-wrap: break-word;">
    <div class="row">
     <div class="col-xs-3">
      <img src="http://placehold.it/40x140">
     </div>
     <div class="col-xs-9">
      <p>bla bla bla</p>
     </div>
    </div>
   </div>
   </div>
  </div>

  <div class="widget">
   <div class="panel panel-info">
   <div class="panel-heading"><p>Header</p></div>
   <div class="panel-body" style="word-wrap: break-word;">
    <div class="row">
     <div class="col-xs-3">
      <img src="http://placehold.it/40x140">
     </div>
     <div class="col-xs-9">
      <p>bla bla bla</p>
     </div>
    </div>
   </div>
   </div>
  </div>
    </div>
   </div>
  </div>
 </div>
    <script>
$(function() {
    $(".navbar").affix({
        offset: {
            top: $("header").outerHeight(true)
        }
    });
});
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's an issue with the navigation's z-index. Even just giving `.navbar` a z-index  of 1 fixed the overlap for me. JSYK, the higher the number the less likely it will be under another element, so you should probably make it something like 999. Try these styles instead.

```
<style>
   .navbar {
      z-index: 1;
    }
    .navbar-collapse {
      background-color: #69899f;
      border-color: #425766;
    }

    .navbar-header {
      background-color: #69899f;
      border-color: #425766;
    }
    .navbar-collapse .navbar-text {
      color: #d7e2e9;
    }
    .navbar-header .navbar-toggle .icon-bar {
      background-color: #d7e2e9;
    }
    .affix {
        top: 0;
        width: 100%;
    }

    .affix+.container-fluid {
        padding-top: 70px;
    }
</style>
```